# How to connect netcat from one local computer to another local computer

Tags: local-area-network, netcat

I want to connect two computers using netcat that are on the different subnets

The problem is when I start Netcat to listen on one computer, I am unable to connect to it from another computer which is on a different Subnet..

Here is a quick sketch to help you understand my problem properly

[Problem Description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7VaHu.jpg)

I have heard a little bit about tunneling. Can it be used to in this case? If yes, then how will i do it practically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your basic problem is that your computers are not only in different subnets, but also reachable over the internet only being behind a NAT environment. So you only can connect to the direct IP addresses connected to the Internet that are *103.255.5.41* and *103.255.5.45*.

To connect both devices directly, you either have to use

- port forwarding on your internet gateway(s), depending on if the listener has to run on both sites
- a VPN solution connecting both sites

With a VPN solution you would not have to make use of tunneling and the connection would be secured. Depending on your routers, these might already ship with a VPN solution.

Using the port forwarding on the internet gateways, you could either use `netcat` directly or tunnel through e.g. `ssh` which I would recommend as I assume you are using `netcat` without ssl.
If you have e.g. port 22 forwarded on the gateway with the IP address *103.255.5.45* to your internal IP address *192.16.43.9*, the following should work.

On *192.16.43.9* start the listener.

```
$ ncat -l 4444
```

On *192.168.8.120* connect to the other site and initiate the SSH tunnel.

```
$ ssh -L localhost:4444:localhost:4444 103.255.5.45
```

Now on *192.168.8.120* you can connect to *localhost:4444* which will be redirected to *192.16.43.9:4444* if everything is configured correctly.

```
ncat localhost 4444
```

The port forward on *103.255.5.45* ensures that a connection to *103.255.5.45:22* is forwarded to *192.16.43.9:22* which makes it possible to SSH to that internal machine.
The `-L localhost:4444:localhost:4444` will open the listener on *192.168.8.120* locally connecting to *192.16.43.9:4444* through SSH.

In either case you need to configure your internet router to establish the connection.

Comment: Thank you, Thomas.
I have another question, what if my gateway is a mobile device and I still want to port forward, Will it be still possible?

Comment: If your mobile device does support that, yes.